# Better way to store large amount of time-series data with tags using python

Tags: python, pickle, dill

I am trying to run a bunch of (power system) simulations and save all the results into dictionaries. Here is the data organization:

Since i have not-so complicated object structure, i decided to use dill to store the dictionary which contains a bunch of dictionaries (each of whose keys contain a class)

```
import dill as pickle

class Results():
    def __init__(self):
        self.volt = []
        self.angle = []
        self.freq = []

def save_obj(obj, name ):
    # save as pickle object
    currentdir = os.getcwd()
    objDir = currentdir + '/obj'
    if not os.path.isdir(objDir):
        os.mkdir(objDir)
    with open(objDir+ '/' +  name + '.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(obj, f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL,recurse = 'True')




EventDict = {}

########### conceptual code to get all the data
# simList is a list of approximately 7200 events
for event in simList:
    ResultsDict = {}
    for element in network: # 24 elements in network (23 buses,or nodes,  and time)
        # code to get voltage, angle and frequency (each of which is a list of 1200 elements)
        if element == 'time':
            ResultsDict['time'] = element
        else:
            ResultsDict[element] = Results()
            ResultsDict[element].volt = element.volt
            ResultsDict[element].angle = element.angle
            ResultsDict[element].freq = element.freq
    EventDict[event] = ResultsDict


save_obj(EventDict,'EventData')
```

The resultant pickle object is like 5 gigs and when i try to load, i get the following error saying it ran out of memory:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "combineEventPkl.py", line 39, in <module>
    EventDict = load_obj(objStr)
  File "combineEventPkl.py", line 8, in load_obj
    return pickle.load(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dill\_dill.py", line 304, in load
    obj = pik.load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 964, in load_binfloat
    self.append(unpack('>d', self.read(8))[0])
MemoryError
no mem for new parser
MemoryError
```

Also, unpickling takes a long time before i get this traceback.
I realize this problem is because the EventDict is huge.
So, i guess i am asking whether there is a better way to store such time series data, with some functionality of labelling each data with a key, so that i know what it represents? I am open to suggestions other than pickle as long as it is fast in loading and  does not involve too much effort in loading into python.

Answer (score 0):

Check out "Fast Data Store for Pandas Time-Series Data using PyStore" https://medium.com/@aroussi/fast-data-store-for-pandas-time-series-data-using-pystore-89d9caeef4e2

May have to chunk the data while reading it in. https://cmdlinetips.com/2018/01/how-to-load-a-massive-file-as-small-chunks-in-pandas/